# How to return North West and South East from Bounding box?

Tags: geolocation, coordinates, gis, bounding-box

I want to return specific direction or North West and Sound East from the Bounding box BBox. Here is the function that I found online that returns bounding box value, however this function returns South West and North East:

```
const getBoundingBox = (data) => {
    var lats = []; var lngs = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
        lats.push(data[0][i][1]);
        lngs.push(data[0][i][0]);
    }

    var minlat = Math.min.apply(null, lats),
        maxlat = Math.max.apply(null, lats);
    var minlng = Math.min.apply(null, lngs),
        maxlng = Math.max.apply(null, lngs);

    bbox = [[minlat, minlng], [maxlat, maxlng]];

    return bbox;
}
```

I tried shifting around things in the function but doesn't seems to return the value I expected. Here's sample polygon I'm trying.

```
{ "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[115.92444, -32.076813], [115.924097, -32.084012], [115.933195, -32.086994], [115.939031, -32.08314], [115.939289, -32.079831], [115.933452, -32.075685], [115.929933, -32.074158], [115.92444, -32.076813]]] };
```

Basically I want to get the North West and Sound East from the above polygon data with help of BBox.

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `bbox = [[minlat, minlng], [maxlat, maxlng]];` returns your SW/NE bounds then all you need to do is `bbox = [[maxlat, minlng], [minlat, maxlng]];` to get the NW/SE bounds.